# Error: Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin cordova-windows. Please try adding it again

Tags: cordova, plugins

I get the following error while trying to install inappbrowser plugin:

```
cordova plugins add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
Error: Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin "cordova-windows". Please try adding it again.
```

I found that this can be fixed by getting the plugin.xml for the plugin and moving it into the appropriate folder. There is no such folder:

[image]

Also, I never installed a plugin "windows"; only a platform "windows" is in use:

```
cordova plugin remove windows
Error: Plugin "windows" is not present in the project. See `cordova plugin list`.

cordova plugins list
cordova-plugin-app-preferences 0.99.3 "AppPreferences"
cordova-plugin-appinfo 2.1.2 "AppInfo Plugin"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.7 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.6 "Device"
cordova-plugin-fullscreen 1.1.0 "cordova-plugin-fullscreen"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.3 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.2 "Whitelist"

cordova platforms list
{}
Installed platforms:
  android 6.2.3
  ios 4.4.0
  windows 5.0.0
Available platforms:
  blackberry10 ~3.8.0 (deprecated)
  browser ~4.1.0
  webos ~3.7.0
```

What is the issue here and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

**cordova-windows** is engine name. I think is a misslogging. You are building for **target** windows (**cordova-window**), and add of **cordova-plugin-inappbrowser** is faulty beacause  **plugin.xml** of that plugin is missing.

All plugins must have **plugin.xml** in root folder (cordova-plugin-inappbrowser\plugin.xml). Try to readd plugin or download plugin.xml from GIT repository of that plugin and copy it to rootfolder of plugin